# Нужно редактировать и сохранить данные из таблицы

Tags: php

Я не очень понимаю все это php, помогите, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы редактировались и сохранялись данные из таблицы.
Вот что я сделал:

```
<form method="POST" action="../../../shorec.php" >
  <input name="FIO" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['FIO']; ?>" type="text">
  <input name="login" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>" type="text">
  <input name="pas" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pass']; ?>" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="obnovite"  value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

Comment: А где таблица? Где сам `shorec.php`?

Comment: <?php 
 function shorec(){
 $db=DataBase::getDB();
 $login=$_POST['login'];//Данные из login
 $pas=$_POST['pas'];//Данные из password
 $FIO=$_POST['FIO'];
 $id=$_POST['Id_uch_zap'];
 $del = $db->mysql_query("UPDATE  `student` SET `FIO`='{$FIO}' WHERE `Id_uch_zap`='{$id}'");
 }
?>

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: И что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Когда  я изменяю данные нажимаю на кнопку сохранить он просто пересылает меня на страницу shorec.php

Comment: так и должно быть. Добавьте в shorec.php редирект на страницу, откуда вызвана функция, с помощью header().

Comment: Мне наверно должно быть стыдно, но что такое редирект

Comment: вам бы основы php учить, а не тут вопросы задавать. книга "php Котеров".

Comment: redirect - перенаправление (на другую страницу). Вы вызываете файл, но внутри него нет исполнения для БД, там у вас функция, но функцию надо тоже вызвать. Можете как вариант убрать  function shorec() и сразу выполнять запрос к БД и хотя бы прочитать основы по PHP. Полно видеоуроков по основам и книг навалом...